# can't get product page from outside using browser via istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, minikube

Hey it's been quite days struggling to make the sample book app running. I am new to istio and trying to get understand it. I followed this [demo](https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-istio-using-docker-desktop/) of an other way of setting up the bookinfo. I am using minikube in a virtualbox machine with docker as a driver. I set metalLB as a loadBalancer for **ingress-gateway**, here is the configmap i used for metalLB :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: custom-ip-space
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.49.2/28
```

the `192.168.49.2` is the result of the command: `minikube ip`

The ingressgateway yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: productpage
            port:
              number: 9080
```

and the output command of `kubectl get svc -n istio-system`:

```
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                                                                                                                      AGE
grafana                  ClusterIP      10.111.105.179   <none>         3000/TCP                                                                                                                                     34m
istio-citadel            ClusterIP      10.100.38.218    <none>         8060/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                           34m
istio-egressgateway      ClusterIP      10.101.66.207    <none>         80/TCP,443/TCP,15443/TCP                                                                                                                     34m
istio-galley             ClusterIP      10.103.112.155   <none>         443/TCP,15014/TCP,9901/TCP                                                                                                                   34m
istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   10.97.23.39      192.168.49.0   15020:32717/TCP,80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15029:32199/TCP,15030:30010/TCP,15031:30189/TCP,15032:31134/TCP,15443:30748/TCP   34m
istio-pilot              ClusterIP      10.108.133.31    <none>         15010/TCP,15011/TCP,8080/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                       34m
istio-policy             ClusterIP      10.100.74.207    <none>         9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                 34m
istio-sidecar-injector   ClusterIP      10.97.224.99     <none>         443/TCP,15014/TCP                                                                                                                            34m
istio-telemetry          ClusterIP      10.101.165.139   <none>         9091/TCP,15004/TCP,15014/TCP,42422/TCP                                                                                                       34m
jaeger-agent             ClusterIP      None             <none>         5775/UDP,6831/UDP,6832/UDP                                                                                                                   34m
jaeger-collector         ClusterIP      10.111.188.83    <none>         14267/TCP,14268/TCP,14250/TCP                                                                                                                34m
jaeger-query             ClusterIP      10.103.148.144   <none>         16686/TCP                                                                                                                                    34m
kiali                    ClusterIP      10.111.57.222    <none>         20001/TCP                                                                                                                                    34m
prometheus               ClusterIP      10.107.204.95    <none>         9090/TCP                                                                                                                                     34m
tracing                  ClusterIP      10.104.88.173    <none>         80/TCP                                                                                                                                       34m
zipkin                   ClusterIP      10.111.162.93    <none>         9411/TCP                                                                                                                                     34m
```

and when trying to curl `192.168.49.0:80/productpage` I am getting :

```
*   Trying 192.168.49.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 192.168.49.0: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
myhost@k8s:~$ curl 192.168.49.0:80/productpage
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

and before setting up the metalLB, I was getting connection refused!

Any solution for this please ? as it's been 5 days struggling to fix it.

I followed the steps [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports) and all steps are ok!

Comment: network unreachable means either you don't have network interface, or capabilities. Connection refused is a completely different issue. Unrelated.

Comment: Can I know the reason behind using older version of Istio?

Comment: @Nandan to be honest i don't know which version of istio been installed i thought was the latest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a problem with the `MetalLB` configuration.

You are trying to give `MetalLB` control over IPs from the `192.168.49.2/28` network.
We can calculate for `192.168.49.2/28` network: **HostMin**=`192.168.49.1` and **HostMax**=`192.168.49.14`.

As we can see, your `istio-ingressgateway` LoadBalancer Service is assigned the address `192.168.49.0` and I think that is the cause of the problem.

I recommend changing from `192.168.49.2/28` to a range, such as `192.168.49.10-192.168.49.20`.

---

I've created an example to illustrate you how your configuration can be changed.

As you can see, at the beginning I had the configuration exactly like you (I also couldn't connect to the server using the `curl` command):

```
$ kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                                                                                                       
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.109.75.19   192.168.49.0    


$ curl 192.168.49.0:80/productpage
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

First, I modified the `config` `ConfigMap`:
**NOTE:** I changed `192.168.49.2/28` to `192.168.49.10-192.168.49.20`

```
$ kubectl edit cm config -n metallb-system
```

Then I restarted all the controller and speaker `Pods` to force `MetalLB` to use new config (see: [Metallb ConfigMap update](https://github.com/metallb/metallb/issues/348#issuecomment-442218138)).

```
$ kubectl delete pod -n metallb-system --all      
pod "controller-65db86ddc6-gf49h" deleted
pod "speaker-7l66v" deleted
```

After some time, we should see a new `EXTERNAL-IP` assigned to the `istio-ingressgateway` `Service`:

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                                                                                         AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.106.170.227   192.168.49.10
```

Finally, we can check if it works as expected:

```
$ curl 192.168.49.10:80/productpage                   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Bookstore App</title>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I tested your configuration and it worked inside my VM with `curl` command, when I switched to windows (my host) to access the web page it didn't work (I changed network of my VM from NAT to bridge to be able to access 192.168.49.10/productpage ). Then I switched to docker desktop in windows and installed MetalLB and didn't work too with same configuration. Furthermore, when installing istio in windows OS, I have already in ingressgateway in 'EXTERNAL_IP' localhost and still not able to access the url

Comment: [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#minikube) was created to run Kubernetes locally.
If I think correctly, you should use port/ssh forwarding to access this IP outside the machine that minikube runs on it (see: [minikube access from outside network](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5812#issuecomment-549585039))